# kivy Text Input inherit behavior from Slider

Tags: python, inheritance, kivy

I wish to create a spinner widget in kivy, consisting of a text entry with two small buttons. A value displayed in the text entry will be increased or decreased, depending on which button was pressed.

That is an easy task, but furthermore I wish to change the values with the wheel of the mouse (scrolling up and down when the cursor is located within the text entry).

Since the text entry doesn't have such a behavior, is it possible to inherit the behavior somehow from another widget, like slider? If so, how would that be accomplished?

**EDIT:**

As requested, this is the code until now:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class LoginScreen(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'horizontal'

        self.container_Flow = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', size_hint = (1,1))
        self.text_flow = TextInput(text='500', font_size=40, size_hint = (0.6,1))
        self.button_plus = Button(text = '+', size_hint = (0.2,1))
        self.button_minus = Button(text = '-', size_hint = (0.2,1))
        self.container_Flow.add_widget(self.text_flow)
        self.container_Flow.add_widget(self.button_plus)
        self.container_Flow.add_widget(self.button_minus)

        self.add_widget(self.container_Flow)
        self.button_plus.bind(on_press = self.calc_plus)
        self.button_minus.bind(on_press = self.calc_minus)

    def calc_plus(self, button_plus):
        Q = int(self.text_flow.text)
        self.text_flow.text = str(Q + 25)
    def calc_minus(self, button_minus):
        Q = int(self.text_flow.text)
        self.text_flow.text = str(Q - 25)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Here is an example.

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App

class Example(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.orientation = 'horizontal'
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal', size_hint = (1,1))
        self.text = MyText(text= '500', font_size=40, size_hint = (0.6,0.5), multiline=True)

        self.layout.add_widget(self.text)

        self.add_widget(self.layout)


class MyText(TextInput): # MyText inherits from TextInput class
    def on_touch_down(self, touch): # method to see if mouse is down/moving
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos): # only works if in the textinput region
            if touch.button == 'scrollup': #check mouse wheel up
                self.calc_plus()
            elif touch.button == 'scrolldown': #check mouse wheel down
                self.calc_minus()
    def calc_plus(self):
        Q = int(self.text)
        self.text = str(Q + 25)
    def calc_minus(self):
        Q = int(self.text)
        self.text = str(Q - 25)

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return Example()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```